# Instantaneous rotation field in relation to a developable surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, isometries

I have a ruled surface, let it be given by $\Sigma: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by $(u,v)$ with the rulings along the $u$-lines. Now, let $X: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an infinitesimal isometric deformation (IID) for $\Sigma$ that happens to form a ruled surface with the rulings along $u$-lines again.

I guess that the instantaneous rotation field of this IID should degenerate to a curve. However, I have some difficulty in proving it so my question is this: is my guess correct? and if so, should I make a distinction between the case where $\Sigma$ is developable and the case where it is not for the proof?

Please let me know if you require me to add further details to the question.